# SQL Server "Invalid column name" error | Newbie

Tags: sql-server

I'm busy teaching myself SQL Server, using SQL Server Management Studio. Here's the code producing the error:

```
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID), YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY SalesYear;
```

Why does it throw this error?

> Invalid column name 'SalesYear'.

Comment: In SQL `GROUP BY` is evaluated before `SELECT`. Hence the alias `SalesYear` is not available to `GROUP BY`. You have to use `GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate)` instead.

Comment: You need to use GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate). Aliases cannot be used in Group By.

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid column name 'SalesYear'.

This column will not be there in table `SalesOrderHeader`

`SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID), YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate)`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with [logical query processing model](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)..`Sales year` is called an alias here and as per logical query processing model,below are the operators that are  executed in sequence..

```
1 FROM 
2 WHERE 
3 GROUP BY 
4 HAVING 
5 SELECT
    5.1 SELECT list
    5.2 DISTINCT
6 ORDER BY 
7 TOP / OFFSET-FETCH
```

so ,in above steps ,group by will be executed in 3rd stage and your select will be executed in 5th stage..

This means your alias(which is in select stage) ,will be visible to operators following select (after 5),but not before them..

I would suggest taking a book which teaches basics well and i found Itzik Ben-Gan books to be extremely helpfull [T-SQL Fundamentals Third Edition](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tf3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query and test to get your expected result.

```
DECLARE @SalesOrderHeader TABLE(SalesPersonID INT,SalesOrderID INT,OrderDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @SalesOrderHeader
SELECT 1,101,'20-Mar-2018' UNION ALL SELECT 1,102,'21-Mar-2018' UNION ALL SELECT 1,102,'21-Mar-2018' UNION ALL SELECT 2,202,'21-Mar-2018'

SELECT * FROM @SalesOrderHeader

SELECT SalesPersonID AS SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) NoOfOrder, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
FROM @SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY SalesPersonID,YEAR(OrderDate);
```

Thanks.